# Where/how to store cost for multiple objects without copy/clone?

Tags: c#, algorithm, a-star

I have A* implemented in C# with PointA and PointB being Tile objects with. X, Y, Walkable, Neighbours (size 8 List), cost.

My issue is that this is on the backend for a online game server,  and the tile maps are shared between monsters.  I don't want to copy the grid for each monster trying to move.

For example a map looks like:

```
 Tile[] Tiles;

 public this[int x, int y]
 {
  get {return Tiles[x + y * sizeY];}
 }
```

Before I was cloning all the tiles into a copy before each monster wanted to calculate a move.  But I noticed this was using crap-load of memory. Where should I store the cost in the A-star calculation assigned to each tile (without copying the grid)?

Answer (score 0):

If the array is going to be [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array), i.e. the A* only looks in a small region of the map, you could represent it as a map (e.g. [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C#) of index to value.

You could also consider a priority queue of potential candidate objects, each of which contains the location, cost, heuristic value and reference to the previous candidate, and forget about the array completely.

Although an array of primitives should be quite a bit smaller than an array of objects of the same length. Just make sure you didn't make a few copies (assuming you're not doing a few in parallel), you aren't overreacting to the memory used, and you take into account all memory used elsewhere. Also keep in mind that updating all the values in the array should take less time than creating a new one and populating the values from there.